# ODP .NET statement timeout on update query

Tags: c#, asp.net, plsql, odp.net

**Issue:**

Basically, update statement awaits endlessly ( *ExecuteNonQueryAsync()* ) for some reason.
***Insert*** works just fine, I tried to hardcode a simple update statement with hardcoded parameters(without ***merge***), same story, even tried to remove ***where*** clause and update all rows, again, same problem.

After setting *commandTimeout* to 1s I managed to identiy *TimeoutException*, why it happens? I have no idea.

**Edit:** Plot twist.
Now I have randomly successful updates, which dazes me even more.
I tried basically every possible scenario I could think of to identify any patterns residing in the issue, my only conclusion is that updates success rate is totally random...

Still inserts are working just fine.

---

This is the simplified code portion.

```
public class CipCheckRepository : ICipCheckRepository
{
    private string connectionString = "Data Source=****;User Id=****;PASSWORD=****;Persist Security Info=True;";

    public CipCheckRepository()
    {}

    public async Task InsertOrUpdate(CipCheck cipCheck)
    {
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(connectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = uow.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"
                    MERGE INTO test
                    USING dual
                        ON (id = :CAD_ID)
                    WHEN MATCHED THEN
                        UPDATE SET value = :ISRA_NUMBER
                    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                        INSERT
                        (
                            id,
                            value
                        )
                            VALUES
                        (
                            :CAD_ID,
                            :ISRA_NUMBER
                        )";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CAD_ID", 1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ISRA_NUMBER", cipCheck.IsraNumber);

                cmd.CommandTimeout = 1;

                try
                {
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
                catch (OracleException ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[UnitOfWork](https://i.postimg.cc/15R5hpZP/Screenshot-3.jpg) class is created for abstraction matters.

How can I identify the cause of the never-ending query and what steps can be taken to prevent it?

Comment: A one second timeout isn't a long time. While you'd hope in most cirumstances it'd be quite a bit faster than that, due to server load or if you have a particularly slow query, it could take over a second pretty easily. A 15 or 30 second timeout is more reasonable. Have you run this same command directly against the DB to eliminate C# being a problem here, and to see how long it takes? Use Toad or Tora or SQLPlus etc.

Comment: I tried with the timeout of 60s as well, and yes, I have tried running it in oracle developer. I mentioned that I tried with simplifying this statement to the portions of a plain basic UPDATE, even eliminating the where clause.

Comment: You tried running it with Oracle Developer - what was the result? How long did it take? Also, where is CipCheckRepository.InsertOrUpdate called from?

Comment: Result was satisfying, it took 2ms. CipCheckRepo is called from another class, architecture is rather complex, but I assume you don't have to bother with it as it is all working just fine with insert query. But FYI, there is another class which is parsing the WCF service response, creating entity class and passing it to the InsertOrUpdate which, and it goes even deeper, but as I said, this is all working when its up to inserting a new row.

Comment: Last thing I tried is to update ODP nuget to the latest version, no luck.

Comment: This probably isn't the source of your problem, but you should implement the advice in [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Will give it a shot tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I've been locking the table somehow, after committing all statements via Oracle Developer the quirks are gone.

[image]